# Is there a feature to extract image font property using cloud vision api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, text-extraction, vision-api

Text extraction is used for extracting text from the image. Can we extract the image font properties such as **font family, font style, font size, etc** from a given image using text extraction feature
**Example**
[image]

Expected to extract below following feature

**Font-family:** TimeNewRoman

**Font-size:** 18

**Font-color:** black

Answer (score 2):

The [Cloud Vision API OCR](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr) is currently limited mostly to extracting the actual text in the image and the language. Recognising the specifications of the font of the text is not a feature at the moment.

If you want this feature to be added you can use [GCP's issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to request it. Once you [submit a new feature request for the Vision API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187174&template=1161131) it will be evaluated for its addition.